# remove the tabs in a particular line

Tags: perl, perl-module

This particular question I have tried and could not get anywhere in SO.
My input file is a asembly file which has all the assembly instruction.

**I have this input file :**

```
.src_ref 0 "call.s" 24 first
      0x000000    0x5a80 0x0060         BRA.l 0x60
.src_ref 0 "call.s" 30 first
      0x000002    0x1bc5                RETI
.src_ref 0 "call.s" 31 first
      0x000003    0x6840                MOV R0L,R0L
.src_ref 0 "call.s" 35 first
      0x000004    0x1bc5
```

All I want to do is remove the tab or spaces when I encounter lines with 0x*****

So far I managed this code, but i am unable to remove it.
Tried several options and could not get it working.

**Expected output**

```
0x000000 0x5a80 0x0060 BRA.l 0x60
0x000002 0x1bc5 RETI
0x000003 0x6840 MOV R0L,R0L
```

**So far I wrote a code as**

```
my $filename = 'c:\Desktop\P4x.lst';
my $line = 0;
open(FILE,$filename) or die "Could not read from filename";
my @lines = <FILE>;
chop @lines;    


foreach my $line(@lines) 
    {
        if ($line =~ /      0x*/)
        {
            $line =~ s/[ ]*\|[ ]*\|[ ]*\|[ ]*\|[ ]*/|/g;
            print "$line\n";
        }

    }
```

So here if I encounter the lines with 0x* then I want to remove the extra space.
Can anyone help me please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($line =~ s/^\h+(?=0x)//) {
  $line =~ s/\h+/ /g;
  print $line;
}
```

or from command line,

```
perl -ne 'print if s/^\h+(?=0x)// and s/\h+/ /g' file
```

Comment: Thank you for quick solution. But can we do it using perl script :) :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if ( $line =~ m/\A\s+0x/ ) {
    $line =~ s/\s+/ /g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have the pipe characters `|` in your regex, as there are none in your sample data.

On the face of it, all you need is `s/^\s+(?=0x)//`

In a program, that would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'C:\Desktop\P4x.lst';
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Failed to open "$filename" for input: $!};

while (<$fh>) {
  s/^\s+(?=0x)//;
  print;
}
```

or as a one-liner on the command line

```
perl -pe's/^\s+(?=0x)//'
```

Both solutions send the modified text to STDOUT, and it can be written to a file using redirection.

---

**Update**

If you want to change all whitespace to a single space as well as removing leading whitespace, as `@Сухой27` has understood, then you just need to change

```
s/^\s+(?=0x)//
```

to

```
s/^\s+(?=0x)// and s/\s+/ /g
```